# Matrix and finding basis for the column space

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given a matrix A=

```
1   2   2
3   1   4
4   3   6
```

find a basis for the column space of A. Then express the 3rd column of A in that basis.

My first thought is to use RREF and than get the matrix from the augmented matrix

```
1 0 1.2 |0
0 1 .4  |0
0 0  0  |0
```

from here I get confused/most likely wrong. Since leading 1s are in row 1 and 2 the basis of this matrix would than be vector {[1, 0, 1.2] and [0, 1, .4]} with X1=-1.2X3 and X2=-.4X3. With X3 being arbitrary. If I made a mistake anywhere let me know, I do not know how to finish this problem.

Comment: the columns of $A$ already are a basis for the column space of $A$.

Comment: Okay, yeah. Messed that up than. Where do I go from here.

Comment: @Thoth The columns of $A$ _span_ the column space, but for them to form a basis they must also be linearly independent, which they aren’t.

Comment: Augmenting the matrix with all zeros doesn’t do anything for you since row-reduction isn’t going to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{6}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\3\\4
\end{bmatrix}
+
\frac{2}{5}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\3
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\4\\6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the first two columns are a basis for the column space and this is the expression of the third column in such basis.

Comment: Okay, yeah I messed up my basis for the column space of A. I see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

To find a basis for the column space of $A$, you can certainly apply row reduction, but I find it easier to column-reduce the matrix instead. The non-zero columns of the resulting matrix are a basis for the column space. In this case, after column reduction we end up with $$\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&1&0},$$ so a basis for the column space is $$\left\{\pmatrix{1\\0\\1},\pmatrix{0\\1\\1}\right\}.$$ The second part of the problem should be easy once you have that.